# On the basis of quantity and product price, total price Update

Tags: javascript, html, each

My HTML structure:

```
<div class="pricesection">
        <label id="productPrice">
        <strong>
        <span id="totalprice"> 129,00</span>
        <span>$</span>
        </strong>
        </label>
        <input type="text" value="1" name="am" id="quantity">
        <button class="submitbtn" type="submit">add to Cart</button>
</div>
```

My JS code:

```
$('#quantity').keyup(function(){
  $('#quantity').each(function () {  
  var qty = $('#quantity').val();
  var price = $('#totalprice').val();
  var total = price * qty;
  });

  $('#totalprice').html(total);
});
```

I have found many examples, not suitable. :-(

After entering Quantity Item Price will be Automatically Updated. If "0", letter, "empty" or after canceling Original price must be restored.

I always get "0" value ​​Back!

I am very grateful for any help!

Comment: there is no need of each method.Get rid of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var $totalprice = $('#totalprice');
var price = parseInt($.trim($totalprice.text()).replace(',', '.'));
$totalprice.data('totalprice', price);
$('#quantity').keyup(function(){
    var qty = this.value;
    var price = $totalprice.data('totalprice');
    var total = price * qty;

    $totalprice.html(total ? total : price);
});
```

*Note: The number formatting is not done*

Answer (score 0):

```
   var price = $('#totalprice').val();//this is wrong!!!
```

get the  `html` of span.Not the value

```
var price = $('#totalprice').text();//this is the correct syntax
```

So,Your code becomes--:

```
  $('#quantity').keyup(function () {
        var qty = $('#quantity').val();
        var price = parseInt($('#totalprice').text()); //or $('#totalprice').html()
        var total = price * qty;
        $('#totalprice').html(total);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! how can i Original Price (129) Restore If the input field "0", entering letters and Blank field. ?

http://jsfiddle.net/Uk9t2/

Comment: even if some body changes the value from 1 to 0,129 should remain 129?is this what you are explaining?

Comment: is you problem solved?if yes:tick the answer right,if no:elaborate it properly so that I sove it

Answer (score 0):

Try this........HTML

```
<div class="pricesection">
        <input type="text" id="productPrice"/>
        <strong>
        <span id="totalprice"> 129,00</span>
        <span>$</span>
        </strong>
        <input type="text" value="1" name="am" id="quantity">
        <button class="submitbtn" type="submit">add to Cart</button>
</div>
```

...............JS........

```
$('#quantity').keyup(function(){
  var qty = $('#quantity').val();
  var price = $('#productPrice').val();
  var total = price * qty;

  $('#totalprice').html(total);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is there a loop on `#quantity` ? You don't need that. Try the following code.

```
$('#quantity').keyup(function () {
    var qty = $('#quantity').val();
    var price = parseInt($('#totalprice').text());
    var total = price * qty;
    $('#totalprice').html(total);
});
```

Notice `parseInt($('#totalprice').text());`
`.val()` doesn't work with span so you would have to use `.text()` and parse the result in int

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that `totalprice` is a span, so it doesn't have a `.val()` function (that's only for inputs), use `.text()` instead.

The contents of the span currently has a comma in it, which won't be automatically parsed into a number. You need to use `parseFloat()`, and you need to use a decimal point, not a comma.

`parseFloat("129,50")` is 129
`parseFloat("129.50")` is 129.50

Secondly, you're doing an `each` over your quantity fields but there's only one. Maybe you wanted that for the future (in which case you should use classes not IDs), but here's some JS that should implement the feature you wanted and fix your bug as well (untested):

```
$('#quantity').keyup(function(){
    var qty = $('#quantity').val();
    if (qty && qty > 0){
        var price = parseFloat($('#totalprice').text());
        var total = price * qty;
        $('#totalprice').text(total);
    }
    else{
        //Find a better way of restoring this value
        $('#totalprice').text("129.50");
    }
});
```

Hope this helps. :)